# Forge/DigitalOcean - This site can’t be reached

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, ip, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

This is my first experience with Forge. So I created DigitalOcean account, had Bitbucket from before, made repository. Added .env to environment variables in Forge.

On server IP adress getting

```
This site can’t be reached
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow when server was installed it did not install nginx, and all what was necessary. In Forge was listed what was installed and that was clearly missing. So I decided to destroy it and install new server. New one works like it should.